# Unable to connect php and mysql using LAMP server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I am using VMWARE and done install LAMP server on it. I've create two UBUNTU vm's. One is for system and another one is for database. The insert database in PHP program system should insert in another vm which is specifically for database. I've already make a connection between two vm's using SSH and grant privileges method.

VM 1= For PHP system,
VM 2= For database that PHP data should insert.

This is signup system. I've already created database name as 'authentication' and table as 'users' with name and password in the table.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $db = mysqli_connect("192.168.117.129","root","abc","authentication"); //ip for vm2

 if (isset($_POST['signup_btn'])) {

     $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $rePassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rePassword']);

     if ($password == $rePassword) {
         $password = md5($rePassword);
         $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, password) VALUES('$name', '$password')";
         mysqli_query($db,$sql);

         $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

         header("location: login.php");
         exit;
     }else{
         $_SESSION['message'] = "The two passwords do not match";
     }
 }?>
```

The problem is, when I insert the data in the system, it's unable to connect with mysql database. What should I do?

Comment: First thing you should do is include the exact error message you're seeing, verbatim.

Comment: There's no error. Just it's unable to connect with mysql database. Means the data from the system not insert in the database.

Comment: You need to create a `mysql` user in your database server and point that user to your aplication server....like `CREATE USER 'youchooseanusername'@'ipofthevm1machine' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`

Comment: What makes you think it's unable to connect if there's no error?

Comment: what used of these? because I've done it multiple times and I couldn't understand what should I do next. Sorry I'm just a student and a beginner. This is my project and I should submit this tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: @Hackerman ^^^^

Comment: MySQL queries tend to fail silently. Make sure you're checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way to make sure the queries work like they should.

Comment: @LittlePotato glad to help pal!

Comment: @aynber so should I change **$db** to **$mysqli** ?

Comment: please add `if (mysqli_connect_error())
 {
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
 }` to print the error after the connection

Comment: @Hackerman what should I do after I create the mysql user?

Comment: You need to grant privileges on that user over your database...look for the grant privileges command on google

Comment: No, the variable name is fine. But `mysql_real_escape_string` won't work with mysqli. The `real_escape_string` functions shouldn't be used anyway since they aren't as secure as one might think. Using prepared statements to bypass quoting the variables is much more secure.